# Is CreateCompatibleDC() necessary working with windows on one display?

Tags: c, winapi, bitmap, gdi

This example code manually reads a bitmap file, uses `CreateDIBSection()` to make GDI allocate memory for it, and create an hbitmap handle.  Then it uses a MemoryDC to draw the bitmap to a window DC:

ftp://ftp.oreilly.com/examples/9781572319950/cd_contents/Chap15/DibSect/DibSect.c

```
hdc = BeginPaint (hwnd, &ps) ;
...
hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC (hdc) ;
```

Why can't we use `GetDC()` with `NULL` or with `hwndDesktop` instead?  Why can't we cache the device context instead of repeatedly creating it?

If the machine has only one display device and we are only drawing to windows why do we need to constantly harmonize bitmaps and device contexts?  Once the pixeldata is copied to the buffer provided by GDI, does GDI update it when that HBITMAP is loaded into a DC and drawn on?  If the user also wishes to draw on it is it necessary to synchronize access?  (By calling `GDIFlush()` first?)

It's hard to figure this out when most all of the object properties are opaque and abstracted.  I've read almost all of the related MSDN, a lot of Petzold's book, and some articles:

[Display Device Contexts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/gdi/display-device-contexts)

[CreateCompatibleDC()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Wingdi/nf-wingdi-createcompatibledc)

[CreateDIBSection()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createdibsection)

[Memory Device Contexts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/gdi/memory-device-contexts)

[Guide to Win32 Memory DC](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/224754/Guide-to-Win32-Memory-DC)

[Guide to WIN32 Paint for Intermediates](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2078/Guide-to-WIN32-Paint-for-Intermediates)

[Programming Windows®, Fifth Edition](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/programming-windows-fifth/9780735642225/)

Edit:

I think my question boils down to this:

Is a device context a TYPE of display or is it an INSTANCE of graphical data that is able to be displayed.  A computer typically has only a handful of displays but it could have hundreds of things to display on them.

Comment: You are probably right, but using code that would work on X displays is better than using code that would work on 1 display.

Comment: You can use `SetDIBitsToDevice()` if you don't want to use a source DC.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the answer you were looking for, but here it goes: A device context is a generalized rendering abstraction. It serves as a proxy between your rendering code and the output device. Output can go to the display, a printer or a plotter, an EMF file, or any other supported device. It allows you to use the same rendering code, regardless of the destination; the low-level details are handled for you, depending on the output device, including clipping, scaling, and viewport translation. As far as implementation details go: constructing a DC is a fairly cheap operation.

Comment: Keep in mind, that the official documentation ([Device Contexts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/gdi/device-contexts)) primarily talks about its implementation rather than its purpose.

Answer (score 3):

`GetDC(NULL)` is the screen HDC and the screen is a shared resource, therefore you should only do read/query operations on this HDC. Writing to this HDC is not a good idea on Vista and higher because of the [DWM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_Window_Manager).

Since a HDC can only contain one bitmap, one brush and one pen, Windows/applications obviously need more than one HDC provided by the graphics engine.

You can count on `CreateCompatibleDC` to be relatively cheap operation and I believe Windows has a cache of DCs it can hand out. If you are creating a game/animation type application you might want to cache some of these graphic objects on your own but a normal application should not.

You don't generally call `GDIFlush` unless you are sharing GDI objects across several threads. You can use `SetDIBits` if you want to mix raw pixel bytes access and GDI.

I don't really get the once screen argument, Windows has supported multiple monitors since Windows 98 and there is not much you can do to prevent the user from connecting another monitor.

Comment: So I figure that if you drag a window from one display to another that a new device context is needed.   I'm guessing we have to create a compatible DC in WM_PAINT because that could happen at any time.  Even with multiple displays, today aren't they all going to be 24bit/the same type?

Comment: Windows is pretty much locked at 32bpp these days. In the old days you would handle the palette changed message etc. for 16 and 256 colors.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you are getting hung up on Microsoft's names for things, Microsoft's name "device context" and the names for calls like "CreateCompatibleDC".

"Device Context" is a bad name. The Win32 documentation will tell you that a device context is a data structure for storing the state of a particular device used for rendering graphics commands. This is only partially true. Look at the different kinds of DCs that exist: (1) screen device contexts, (2) printer device contexts, (3) the device context used by a bitmap in memory, and (4) metafile device contexts. Of these only (1) or (2) are actually doing exactly what the documentation claims they are doing. In the other cases device contexts serve as a target for drawing calls but not as containers for the state of some physical device. (This is really noticeably true in the case of metafile DC's: metafiles were an old Win32 thing that basically just cache the GDI calls going in to them to be replayed later, kind of a crude vector format.)

In a hypothetical object oriented programming version of Win32, device contexts could be instances of some class that implements an interface that exposes graphics drawing calls. A better name for such a class would be something like "Graphics" and indeed in GDI+ this is what the analogous construct is actually called. When we "Create" -- via CreateDC, CreateCompatibleDC, etc. -- we create one of these objects. When we GetDC we grab such an object that already exists.

To answer your questions:

*Is a device context a TYPE of display or is it an INSTANCE of graphical data that is able to be displayed. ?*

They are in so sense types of displays. You can think of them as instances of a class of objects with private implementations that expose a public interface exposing drawing commands.

*Why can't we use GetDC() with NULL or with hwndDesktop instead?*

You can't use GetDC(NULL) as the device context into which you are going to select an in memory bitmap because in such a situation you need to create a device context that does not already exist; GetDC(NULL) is like a singleton instance that is already in use.

So instead you usually CreateCompatibleDC(NULL) or CreateCompatibleDC(hdcScreen). Again CreateCompatibleDC(...) is a confusing name. Imagine the hypothetical object-oriented version of what is going on here. Say there is an IGraphics interface that is implemented by RasterGraphics, PrinterGraphics, and MetafileGraphics. Imagine the "RasterGraphics" class is used for both the screen and for in memory bitmaps. Then CreateCompatibleDC(...) would be would be like a factory call Graphics.CreateFrom(IGraphics g) that return a new instance of the same concrete type with perhaps some state variables initialized.

*Why can't we cache the device context instead of repeatedly creating it?*

You can. You do not need to delete device contexts across function calls. The only reason people often do is that they are a shared, finite resource and creating them is cheap. I think actually that they used to be very limited under old versions of Windows so old Win32 programmers tend to not cache them out of muscle memory from the old days, from Windows 95 days.

*If the machine has only one display device and we are only drawing to windows why do we need to constantly harmonize bitmaps and device contexts?*

Don't think of the "compatible" in CreateCompatibleDC(...) to be about "harmonizing with the screen" think of it as meaning "Okay Windows I want to create one of your graphics interface objects and I want the kind like this one, which is a normal raster graphics one and not for printers or for metafiles."

Comment: You are breaking an abstraction into constituent parts, that do not exist. The proposed DC (3) does not exist. *Every* DC has an in-memory bitmap selected into it. And you can render into it like you do into any other DC. Likewise, DC (4) does exactly, what it is meant to do: Provide a means to produce an object that can be displayed. The true reason why you do not want to cache the DC returned from `BeginPaint` is not one of scarceness either. It should not be cached, because the clipping rectangle may be different at any time, e.g. when the window has been resized.

Comment: The one from begin paint should not be cached that is true. Dcs that we’re created can be cached

Comment: Besides, *"device context"* is not Microsoft terminology. It's an established name for a pattern Microsoft are implementing. I first came across it in *"Computer Graphics: Principles and Practice"*, published in 1982. And there is nothing hypothetical about its object-oriented nature in Windows either. Device contexts exhibit *all* [object-oriented concepts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_design#Object-oriented_concepts).

Comment: I use “hypothetical” et al to address your primary concern: I am talking about an abstraction into parts that does not exist. Look, the answer was trying to be instill a mental model that helps when dealing with this part of win32 by way of metaphor for people who are used to first class OOP rather than ad hoc C-style OOP . such mental models can be useful without being totally correct. In fact if they were entirely accurate, they would not be models. If you do not find such cutting of corners for pedagogical purposes useful, fine, I can understand that.

Comment: Building a mental model is important. Simplification is good, too, as long as the simplified story captures core concepts. That's where this proposed answer goes wrong: It invents 4 different types of DC's (one of which doesn't even exist), and proposes, that they were somehow different. Yet, they all have the same interface, and are used in the same way. In fact, it is the main purpose of a device context to hide the per-device implementation details, and provide a consistent interface to clients across all devices. This is not a detail either; this a *fundamental* aspect.

Comment: @IInspectable, re: "...because the clipping rectangle may be different at any time, e.g. when the window has been resized."  Is there a DC for every aspect of a window - one for every control, different regions, the client area? The mental model is what I'm struggling with.  Thanks!

P.S. I grabbed a tool that shows GDI usage somewhat.  For future readers of this post: https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/gdi_handles.html

Comment: I have some code take a screenshot, not necessarily even having its own window.  What's the appropriate way to create a memDC to bitblt the screen to?
hwndDesktop = GetDesktopWindow(), hdcDesktop = GetDC(hwndDesktop), assert(hdcMemoryTemp = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcDesktop))

Does every window have (only?) one associated DC for drawing?

Comment: @use: You seem to be stuck on the idea, that you were drawing **to** a device context. If you think of this as rendering **through** a device context instead, things will start to make more sense. DC's are usually shared (I don't know at what granularity, though), unless a window class registers the `CS_CLASSDC` or `CS_OWNDC` [window class styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/window-class-styles). This is rarely needed, and really is an implementation detail that leaked out of the abstraction.